# Using AEM sling rewriter to replace one string in html with another

Tags: java, osgi, aem, aem-6

I am new to using Sling rewriter however I would like to replace all instances of one string with another string (this is a simplified version of my use case but should be enough for understanding). I'm having trouble finding code snippets on how to achieve this use case and I am not familiar with AEM Sling rewriter or how to set it up for custom html rewrites. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check this one [AEM: links transform/rewrite in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166792/aem-links-transform-rewrite-in-a-page) and https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/commons/rewriter/impl/StaticReferenceRewriteTransformerFactory.java